# What are the possible 'types' available in SQL Server as mentioned in the 'type' column in the sys.master_files view?

Tags: sql-server

I'm relatively new to SQL Server, and having a problem with an expanding tempdb database. As such, I'm starting to look just more generally into how database files work.

Looking at this query:

```
USE master;
SELECT *
FROM sys.master_files mf
```

I understand looking at the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-master-files-transact-sql) that the `sys.master_files` view keeps track of files related to databases. On my system the 'type' column is only either `0` or `1` - i.e. I only have `Log` and `Row` files. But the docs mention types `2` (FILESTREAM), `3` (...), and ,`4` (Full text).

Questions:

1. Would `.mdf` files always be type `0`? It seems this is the file that represents a database; I didn't realize that all database objects would be represented by 'Row'-type files
2. What is the type `FILESTREAM`?
3. How are tables differentiated in files of type `Rows`?

===== EDIT

Question 1 is a little misleading; the answer mentions that .mdf and other SQL Server file extensions are just SQL Server's default file extensions and that these can be changed. Testing this, it looks like data is written to the files in exactly the same way regardless of file extension.

Comment: You might want to consider [editing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/180223/edit) your question to add as much detail as possible, like what have you so far researched and what do you want to achieve? This might possibly remove the down votes and allow this question to stay open on DBA.SE for the benefit of future users seeking information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't mix file extensions with file types. You have to differentiate between file extensions and what the files actually contain.

### Create Database (non-standard)

It is possible to create a database that has *.txt as the file extension for the Data files ("ROWS Data" type) which are otherwise created with an *.mdf or *.ndf extension.

It is equally possible to create a database that has a *.txt extension for the TransactionLog file ("Log" type) which is otherwise created with an *.ldf file extension.

#### Script to create a non-standard database

```
CREATE DATABASE [File_Types]
    CONTAINMENT = NONE
    ON  PRIMARY 
   ( NAME = N'File_Types', FILENAME = N'C:\SQL\SQL_DATA\File_Types.txt' , SIZE = 5120KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ), -- normally *.mdf
   ( NAME = N'File_Types_01', FILENAME = N'C:\SQL\SQL_DATA\File_Types_01.txt' , SIZE = 5120KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ), -- normally *.ndf
    FILEGROUP [File_Types_FS_FG] CONTAINS FILESTREAM 
   ( NAME = N'File_Types_FS', FILENAME = N'C:\SQL\FILESTREAM\File_Types_FS' ) -- no extension; is a directory where BLOBs are stored
   LOG ON 
   ( NAME = N'File_Types_log', FILENAME = N'C:\SQL\SQL_LOGS\File_Types_Log.txt' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 10%) -- normally *.ldf
GO
USE [File_Types]
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.filegroups WHERE is_default=1 AND name = N'PRIMARY') ALTER DATABASE [File_Types] MODIFY FILEGROUP [PRIMARY] DEFAULT
GO
```

This will create a database with three files which all have the *.txt extension.

#### Query sys.master_files

```
SELECT database_id, FILE_ID, TYPE, type_desc, NAME, mf.physical_name
  FROM sys.master_files AS mf WHERE database_id = 13
```

#### Output

```
database_id FILE_ID type_desc   NAME            physical_name  
13          1       ROWS        File_Types      C:\SQL\SQL_DATA\File_Types.txt  
13          2       LOG         File_Types_log  C:\SQL\SQL_LOGS\File_Types_Log.txt  
13          3       ROWS        File_Types_01   C:\SQL\SQL_DATA\File_Types_01.txt  
13      65537   2   FILESTREAM  File_Types_FS   C:\SQL\FILESTREAM\File_Types_FS
```

### To answer your questions

1. "DATA Rows" will always be type `1`. A file with an *.mdf extension can be of any type.
2. FILESTREAM integrates the SQL Server Database Engine with an NTFS file system by storing varbinary(max) binary large object (BLOB) data as files on the file system. Transact-SQL statements can insert, update, query, search, and back up FILESTREAM data. Win32 file system interfaces provide streaming access to the data. (see: [FILESTREAM Overview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx))
3. Tables are stored in pages and extents inside the "Data ROWS" database files. An explanation of how data is stored can be found here: [Understanding Pages and Extents](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969(v=sql.105).aspx) and [Managing Space Used by Objects](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187501(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: Thanks! what would be the benefit of changing the file extension? I've just tried this and it looks like it doesn't change the way that the database writes to the files (i.e. it looks as if I had taken a .mdf file, changed the extension to .txt and then tried to open it).

On another note, would it be possible to read a database file in sublime or something like that? What encoding is used?

Comment: No benefit, expect if you want to "hide" the database files. *.mdf, *.ndf and *.ldf are the defaults. You can't change the file extension after the database has been created, unless you `MOVE` the database files with an `ALTER DATABASE ...` statement. Nothing changes if you change the extension. The content stays the same and the binary encoding is still the same. You might be able to read a database file with a HEX Editor, but you will not be able to "see" the database as SQL Server interprets it. Please read the links I provided.